# layout-sw480dp-land work with emulator but not with the phone

Tags: android, screen

I need to create a layout land for phones with 5" and above.

I used layout-sw480dp-land but it didn't work when I tested it with my LG G2.

Then I tried layout-xlarge-land and layout-large-land and it didn't work either.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't accept this folder at all :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the correct answer is layout-sw360dp-land

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sw` in `layout-sw480dp-land` stands for "smallest width." That means that the layout files in this folder will be used for devices whose smallest width (portrait width) is 480dp or greater when in landscape mode. The `dp` stands for "density independent pixels," so even though the G2 has a resolution of 1080x1776, its `dp` resolution is only 360x592. 360 < 480, so it doesn't match your folder criteria.

If you change your folder to be named `layout-sw360dp-land` then your G2 should use those layout files when in landscape mode.

See also: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: How do you calculate 360x592 dp from 1080x1776